# Using on() with a map

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to refactor my code and decided to re-implement my `on` events by mapping

Here's what i have:

```
$('img#sorc').on({

mousemove: function (e) {
alert('test in');
}

  }, {

mouseleave: function () {
alert('test out');
  }
});
```

Now mouseleave won't work.
I checked my code x10 and stared at it for so long, what did i miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have additional `}, {` remove it with `,`

```js
$('img#sorc').on({
  mousemove: function(e) {
    alert('test in');
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    alert('test out');
  }
});
```

Comment: Oh i thought you need to enclose them both with `{ }`, i missed that one. thank you

Comment: @CarlosMiguelColanta : glad to help